# Self-study genetics

Tags: dna, genomics, literature

I'm new at the field of genomics. I'm a theoretical physicist by training and now we would like to translate some of the ideas to the DNA, possibly in real genomic instances. The concrete example would be the line contained for example in [this book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/3540724931), charge migration in DNA.

Before jumping to this specific line of research, I would like to understand more fully the general theory on DNA and genomics. I have read that [Lewis, Genes](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1284104494) is kind of standard, but I'm too far from this text at this time. What books would you recommend to self study from scratch?

Extra points will go to someone who can give also references for a basic course in molecular biology; it has been a while since I took chemistry, so I have been rusty at this topic also.

Comment: What does "I'm too far from this text at this time" mean?

Answer (score 3):

I used "Essential cell biology" by Albert et al,
and then "Molecular biology of the cell" for  more detail. Also by them.
Experts originally from other fields contribute greatly to biology, so dont be discouraged. For self education (which I did before formal study) I recommend incremental learning based on learning everything about a drug, disease, molecule etc of interest and work out from there.

In "Biochemistry" by Lehninger, browse and look at the side panels and pictures and work through the interesting ones.

Good luck